# Linux Terminal Simulator

Tags: text-based

I am planning on making a command shell game, and I want to know what the best way to provide a shell environment is for this.

I would like to be able to provide most of the standard utilities most terminal-users would expect from a terminal, such as `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, or `man`, but I also need to be able to customize and modify some of it (in particular `ssh`, all network interfacing, and a custom package manager) to be able to provide the intended gameplay.

In particular, I need to be able to display images in the terminal, e.g. via [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/fbi.1.html), although there is no need to be able to use a full graphical environment - no X.

I've considered various computer emulators such as [v86.js](https://github.com/copy/v86) or [jslinux](https://github.com/levskaya/jslinux-deobfuscated). These could be customized by providing a disk image, and work exactly like real computers - I would just need to modify the disk image to get it to work the way I want. Doing this approach, I would certainly learn a lot about the inner workings of linux, but it would take a lot of time to do this.

Another option would be to implement my own console to do this. This *might* be simpler to do, but I don't think I would be able to provide as authentic an experience this way.

What would be the best (easiest/simplest) way to create/customize a command shell for this purpose?

Comment: I believe you would receive more/better answers if you asked this on stack overflow instead, as your question is more related to general programming than game development.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt You're probably right. Flagged for migration.